# Finding a sport composed of multiple other sports

Tags: olympics

I am 100% sure that it was in the past 2 Olympics but not the most recent in 2016. The sport was about running but there is a twist that a competitor has to complete other tasks like shooting, swimming and other stuff in a single race.

A team who managed to do everything first are winners. What sport could this have been?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're describing the **modern pentathlon**. Running, shooting, and swimming are three of the five events it contains - the other two are fencing and show-jumping.

> The modern pentathlon is an Olympic sport that comprises five different events; fencing (one-touch épée), freestyle swimming (200 m), equestrian show jumping (15 jumps), and a final combined event of pistol shooting and cross country running (3200 m).
>   <sub>- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_pentathlon)</sub>